# Automapper Project() to IEnumerable and single Objects

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper, automapper-3

I have two of class that will be map with another. `MyViewClass` and `MyDomainClass`

```
public class EntityMapProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<MyDomainClass, MyViewClass>();
    }
}
```

So I need to an extension method to map domain object to view object.

```
public static class MyClassMapper
{
    public static MyViewClass ToView(this MyDomainClass obj)
    {
        return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<MyDomainClass, MyViewClass>(obj);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<MyViewClass> ToView(this IEnumerable<MyDomainClass> obj)
    {
        return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MyDomainClass>, IEnumerable<MyViewClass>>(obj);
    }
}
```

But I have so many domain and view classes. So I need to create create so many extension methods and classes.

Is there any way to do this a generic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automapper already using generics so I don't any issues using direct mapper instead of extension e.g.

```
var view = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<MyDomainClass, MyViewClass>(domain);
```

However you could write extension for IEnumerable mapping:

```
public static IEnumerable<TView> MapEnumerable<TDomainModel, TView>(this IEnumerable<TDomainModel> domainEnumerable)
            where TDomainModel : class
            where TView : class
        {
            return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TDomainModel>, IEnumerable<TView>>(domainEnumerable);
        }
```

And use it like:

```
IEnumerable<MyViewClass> views = domainEnumerable.MapEnumerable<MyDomainClass, MyViewClass>();
```

Update:
Extension for single domain model

```
public static TView MapDomain<TDomainModel, TView>(this TDomainModel domainModel)
            where TDomainModel : class
            where TView : class
        {
            return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TDomainModel, TView>(domainModel);
        }
```

Comment: Automapper has generics but I need use AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<> all time. If I create extension method, I can use it everywhere. Thanks.

Comment: I updated answer with single domain model map extension too